Notion of proof for first-order formulas with parameters
When proof in first-order logic is formalized by the statement $T\vdash\phi$, it is required that $T$ is a set of sentences, i.e. formulas with no parameters. Gödel's completeness theorem states that if a sentence $\phi$ holds in all models of $T$, then $T\vdash\phi$.
I am guessing that the lack of parameters here may be the cause of some phenomena that I find a bit aesthetically unappealing, like the fact that there are only countably many large cardinal axioms even though notions like "$\alpha$-strong" could theoretically be defined for any ordinal $\alpha$, and perhaps the necessity of "parameter-free" in Theorem E of Aguilera and Pakhomov's "The $\Pi^1_2$ consequences of a theory" (p. 5).
Is there any existing notion of proof for first-order logic that includes parameters with fixed interpretations? Specifically, has there ever been a definition published of a relation $\widetilde{\vdash}$ such that for a set of first-order sentences $T$ and a formula $\phi$ altogether in which there appear at most countably many parameters $(p_i)_{i<\nu\leq\omega}$, if $(M,(p_i)_{i<\nu})\vDash T$ implies $(M,(p_i)_{i<\nu})\vDash\phi$ for all $M$, then $T\,\widetilde{\vdash}\,\phi$?
It is the case that when using the usual relation $\vdash$, the sentences in $T$ are allowed to contain constant symbols $(c_i)_{i\in I}$, in which case, if a sentence $\phi$ holds in all models $(M,(c_i)_{i\in I})$ of $T$, then $T\vdash\phi$. But this does not give a notion of proof for formulas with parameters, since the symbols $c_i$ are not required to be interpreted one way.

How do you talk about parameters without fixing a model at the outset? And if you fix a specific model to start with, how do you avoid just recovering the theory of that particular model?

A formula $\phi$ has a finite number of terms and cannot have an infinite number of parameters, unless you can redefine "formula" in some useful way.

Or maybe by "parameters" you don't mean "unbound variables".

@aschepler The set ${c_i\mid i\leq n}$ is the set of parameters appearing across all formulae in $T$, for example if $(T_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is an enumeration of $T$, it may be the case that $p_0$ appears in $T_0$, $p_1$ appears in $T_1$, etc. I am implementing parameters in the formulas via constant symbols with an interpretation fixed by the choice of individuals $p_i$. (As $n$ may be $\omega$ I will edit to change the letter used for the variable.)

So $\phi$ is an ordinary formula, having a finite subset of $(p_i)_{i<\nu}$ as unbound parameters?

@aschepler Yes, I have also now added a word which may make more clear that $\phi$ may not have infinitely many parameters.

@NoahSchweber First we choose a set $T$ of sentences which have at most countably many constant symbols $(c_i){i\in\mathbb N}$ among them, and we choose a sequence of sets $(p_i){i<\nu\leq\omega}$. Then instead of considering all models $\mathfrak M$ such that $\mathfrak M\vDash T$ as is usually done in completeness, only consider models $\mathfrak M=(M,\ldots)$ such that $p_i\in M$ for all $i<n$ and $\mathfrak M$ interprets $c_i$ as $p_i$. (cont'd)

About recovering the theory of the model, are you asking about what prevention there is from defining $T,\widetilde{\vdash},\phi$ to be the trivial "$\phi$ holds in all models $\mathfrak M=(M,\ldots)$ of $T$ such that such that $p_i\in M$ for all $i<n$ and $\mathfrak M$ interprets $c_i$ as $p_i$"?

How do parameters "appear in" the sentences in $T$?

@aschepler Oops, I should have written "the set of constant symbols appearing across all formulae in $T$", "$c_0$ appears in $T_0$", etc. If $(T_i){i\in\mathbb N}$ is an enumeration of $T$, each sentence $T_i$ may contain some finite number of constant symbols $c_{i_0},\ldots,c_{i_k}$. These constant symbols are what appear in the sentences of $T$, and there are countably many of these. In all models under consideration in this question, $c_{i_j}$ will be interpreted as the set $p_{i_j}$, making $c_{i_j}$ the name and $p_{i_j}$ the parameter.

But "interprets $c_i$ as $p_i$" doesn't place any meaningful constraint on the models. For any structure $\mathfrak{A}=(A;...)$, element $a\in A$, and set $p$, there is an isomorphic $\mathfrak{A}'=(A';...)$ such that $p\in A'$ and $\mathfrak{A}\cong \mathfrak{A}'$ via a bijection sending $p$ to $a$. So the "parameter symbols" behave identically to constant symbols.

@NoahSchweber This is enough to resolve the question! If you prefer to add this as an answer I would accept it, even though this was a reference-request question.

@C7X 'Tis done!

Turning my comment into an answer:
"Interprets $c$ as $p$" for $p$ a fixed set actually places no meaningful constraint on the behavior of $c$ across models. This is because we can always "rearrange the domain" however we want: for any structure $\mathfrak{A}=(A;...)$, any $a\in A$, and any set $p$, we can find a set $B\ni p$ and bijection $f:A\rightarrow B$ with $f(a)=p$. When we "transport the structure" of $\mathfrak{A}$ along $f$, we get an isomorphic structure $\mathfrak{B}=(B;...)$ in which $p$ behaves exactly as $a$ did in $\mathfrak{A}$ (that is, $f:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}$ is an isomorphism with $f(a)=p$).
Things change if we require that the structures in question "view" the given set $p$ in a particular way - e.g. if we're looking at $\{\in,...\}$-structures we could demand that $\in$ be interpreted as the usual elementhood relation and that our structures be transitive, and this would have meaningful implications - but that would also drastically change the overall behavior of the logic (even ignoring parameters) from the usual FOL.
